# Accessing items from a frozenset in python

Tags: python, frozenset

I have a frozenset given as `x = frozenset({"a":1,"b":2})`. I am not able to figure out a way to be able to access the items in the dict. Is there a way to unfreeze the frozenset? Given below is the error I get.

```
In [1]: x = frozenset({"a":1,"b":2})

In [2]: x
Out[2]: frozenset({'a', 'b'})

In [3]: x["a"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c47cedd3f38d> in <module>()
----> 1 x["a"]

TypeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Frozenset is a set not dict.

Comment: the `frozenset` constructor takes an iterable, like the `set` constructor. When you iterate over a `dict`, you iterate over it's *keys*. I'm not sure why you expect a `x['a']` to work on a set, though. That is a dictionary behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to "unfreeze" it.....and access the dict within?

Comment: @lordlabakdas There is no dict within!

Comment: And the problem is not the freezing, it is the set. As Ashwini says, a set is not a dict. You would get the same issue with a standard `set()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `frozenset` constructor takes an iterable! As mentioned in the comments, when you iterate a `dict`, you are only iterating its keys, therefore the values are lost.

```
x = frozenset({"a": 1,"b": 2})
# frozenset(['a', 'b'])
```

You can create it form the `dict`'s items though:

```
x = frozenset({"a": 1, "b": 2}.items())
# frozenset([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
```

Now you can simply turn it back into a `dict`:

```
d = dict(x)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access the elements would be to access them through a list, so let a frozen set be created in the way that @user2390182 created it:

```
x = frozenset({"a": 1,"b": 2}.items())
```

Then one can create a list by:

```
d = list(x)
# [('a',1),('b',2)]
```

With a list conversion one can also iterate over single element frozen sets, so:

```
x2 = frozenset({"a","b"})
```

The conversion is shown below:

```
d2 = list(x2)
# ['a','b']
```

But converting the single element frozen set to a dict fails:

```
d2 = dict(x2)
# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```